# Cisco Netflow exporter inactive

Tags: cisco, router, netflow

I have difficulty configuring Netflow on Cisco router ASR 1001

```
flow record FLOW-RECORD-1
 match ipv4 source address
 match ipv4 destination address
 match ipv4 protocol
 match ipv4 tos
 match interface input
 match transport source-port
 match transport destination-port
 collect interface output
 collect transport tcp flags
 collect counter bytes long
 collect counter packets long
 collect timestamp absolute first
 collect timestamp absolute last
flow exporter FLOW-EXPORT-1
 destination 10.251.43.81
 source TenGigabitEthernet0/0/0.254
 ttl 60
 transport udp 9995
 export-protocol netflow-v5
flow monitor FLOW-MONITOR-AKT1
 exporter FLOW-EXPORT-AKT1
 cache timeout active 5
 cache entries 20000
 record FLOW-RECORD-AKT1
 ip flow monitor FLOW-MONITOR-1 input
```

However the exporter is inactive and my server is not collecting data

```
AKT-SK-ASR-1001-X#sho flow monitor
Flow Monitor FLOW-MONITOR-AKT1:
  Description:       User defined
  Flow Record:       FLOW-RECORD-AKT1
  Flow Exporter:     FLOW-EXPORT-AKT1 (inactive)
  Cache:
    Type:                 normal (Platform cache)
    Status:               allocated
    Size:                 16 entries
    Inactive Timeout:     15 secs
    Active Timeout:       5 secs
    Trans end aging:   off
```

We had a Cisco 7206 and the server working just fine but since the ASR is not accepting the configuration of the 7206 i can't figure out what is the problem.

Please give me any advice how to troubleshoot.

BR,